# Sturm-Liouville BVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, consider the boundary value problem (BVP)

$$x^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+2x\frac{dy}{dx}+\lambda y=0, x \in [1,2]$$$$ y(1)=y(2)=0$$

which of the following statements are correct?

(a) there exists a $\lambda_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the BVP has a non-trivial solution for any $\lambda > \lambda_0$

(b) { $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ $|$ the BVP has a non-trivial solution } is dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$

(c) for any continuous function $f:[1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)\not=0$ for some $x \in [1,2]$, there exists a solution $u$ of the BVP for some $\lambda$ such that $\int_{1}^{2} fu \not=0$

(d) there exists a $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the BVP has two linearly independent solutions.

What I did so far: It's a regular Sturm-Liouville BVP; so the eigen-values are simple. So option d is not correct. And only countably many eigenfuctions could be there for the BVP, so we can reject option b. but I have no idea for options a and c.

Comment: Your statement about countability rules out (a); it technically does not rule out (b), since $\mathbb{R}$ has countable dense subsets. For (c), a different way to look at the same statement is to view the negation as saying that the eigenfunctions all lie the $L^2$-orthogonal complement of the span of some continuous function.

Comment: I did not really get the point, could you please explain how countability rules out a? thanks in advance.

Comment: $\{ \lambda \in \mathbb{R} : \lambda > \lambda_0 \}$ is not countable.